# I face this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class java.lang.Object

Tags: android-studio, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I am new with MVVM in kotlin, I want to fetch some data using retrofit and show this in textview but I can't fetch this. In this app first time, I am using the android jetpack component. I tried a lot of times but I can't solve this error. My code in below

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val repository = Repository()
    val viewModelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(repository)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getEmployeeData()

    viewModel.repoResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d("Response", response.body()?.employee_id.toString())
            Log.d("Response", response.body()?.employee_name.toString())
            Log.d("Response", response.body()?.employee_age.toString())
            Log.d("Response", response.body()?.employee_salary.toString())

            name.text = response.body()?.employee_name!!

        } else {
            Log.d("Response", response.errorBody().toString())
            name.text = response.code().toString()
        }
    })
}
```

MainViewModelFactory.kt

```
class MainViewModelFactory(private val repository: Repository):ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return MainViewModel(repository) as T
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel(private val repository: Repository):ViewModel() {
val repoResponse:MutableLiveData<Response<Employee>> = MutableLiveData()
fun getEmployeeData(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = repository.getEmployeeData()
        repoResponse.value = response
    }
}
```

ApiClient.kt

```
object ApiClient {
private val retrofit by lazy{
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

val api:Api by lazy {
    retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
}
```

Api.kt

```
public interface Api {

@GET("api/v1/employee/1")
suspend fun getEmployeeData():Response<Employee>
}
```

Repository.kt

```
class Repository {
suspend fun getEmployeeData():Response<Employee>{
    return ApiClient.api.getEmployeeData()
}
```

Employee.kt

```
data class Employee(
@SerializedName("id")
var employee_id: Int,
@SerializedName("employee_name")
var employee_name: String,
@SerializedName("employee_age")
var employee_age: Int,
@SerializedName("employee_salary")
var employee_salary: Int
)
```

Constants.kt

```
class Constants {
companion object{
    const val BASE_URL = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com"
}
```

Error image
[image]

How can i solve this? please help me. Thank you

Comment: What is your Retrofit version?

Comment: my retrofit version is 2.3.0,please help me.Thank you

Comment: Suspend is only supported since 2.6.0. The latest version is 2.9.0. Please update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrofit only supports suspend keyword since 2.6.4, so using 2.3.0 won't work.

You should update to a newer version of Retrofit. The current latest version at the time of writing is 2.9.0.

Comment: now i am facing this error java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to dummy.restapiexample.com not permitted by network security policy

Comment: @user10997009 that goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted